# Definition of sectional curvature of graph and relation to smooth sectional curvature

Tags: graph-theory, curvature

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold.
Let $\tau$ be a triangulation, i.e. a simplicial complex together with a fixed homeomorphism to $M$.
By forgetting about all cells except $0$-cells and $1$-cells of the complex, we get a graph $\Gamma_{\tau}$.
Write $\tau_k$ for the $k$-th barycentric subdivision of $\tau$, i.e. $\tau_k$ are finer and finer triangulations of $M$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

> Is there a notion of sectional curvature for graphs with the property that the sectional curvature of $\Gamma_{\tau_k}$ "converges" to the sectional curvature of $(M,g)$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$?

Here, "converges" is in quotation marks, because the sectional curvature of a graph and of a manifold live in different spaces, so some work would need to go into making this precise.

In the article "Ollivier-Ricci curvature convergence in random geometric graphs" by
Pim van der Hoorn, William J. Cunningham, Gabor Lippner, Carlo Trugenberger, Dmitri Krioukov something like this is described for the Ricci curvature.